# Why this works out of UpdatePanel but not inside UpdatePanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have copy and paste this Alert Class:
http://madskristensen.net/post/JavaScript-AlertShow%28e2809dmessagee2809d%29-from-ASPNET-code-behind.aspx

It works except with a button inside an update panel but it shows no error. The asp code inside is executed but nothing shows up on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registering the Javascript with `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` rather than `page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` will take care of registering scripts during partial page updates. Here's the modified code:

```
public static void Show(string message)
{
    // Cleans the message to allow single quotation marks
    string cleanMessage = message.Replace("'", "\\'");
    string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('" + cleanMessage + "');</script>";

    // Gets the executing web page
    Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

    if (page != null)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page, typeof(Alert), "alert", script, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks then subsequent question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533995/how-to-reference-a-scriptmanager-from-httpcontext-current-currenthandler

Comment: Also do know why just because it's in update panel, this didn't work ?

Comment: You do not need to find your instance of the Script Manager control on your page, `RegisterClientScriptBlock` is a static method of the `ScriptManager` class, so the code above will work as is

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not to use updatePanels at all, implement scriptable webservice and access it via proxy kindly generated for you by asp.net
it will save you tons of nerves as well as time, because updatepanel is really really buggy

Comment: Good Idea, do you have a tutorial for that , Thanks.

Comment: it is really easy, you can take a look at http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/HOW%20TO%20Call%20WCF%20Web%20Services.ashx