# How to reference a scriptmanager from HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler?

Tags: asp.net

I reference the current page in a class with

```
Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
```

I know need to reference ScriptManager1. What the syntax ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ScriptManager sm = (ScriptManager)page.FindControl("ScriptManager1");

if(sm != null)
{
    // Control found

}
```

Comment: Thank you didn't know about FindControl, though Finally someone told me I could directly use ScriptManager so I don't need to find any reference.

Answer (score 6):

Or

```
Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

if (page != null)
{
    ScriptManager smgr = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(page);
}
```

Comment: No, you can have a single ScriptManager control on each page.